# Configure Domino to use SMTP routing and hMailServer

Tags: smtp, ibm-domino

I have been trying for a couple of days to set up a Domino 8.5 server. Basically, I want everything to be run inside a local network. Right now I can send email to other user in the Domino directory without any mail address. I am pretty new to all this stuff, so maybe the answer will be really obvious.

What I need to do is be able to send a mail from somewhere else to a domino user that will be redirected to his account.

On the Domino server, I also have hMailServer installed on port 25. I configured Domino to use port 26.

I followed those step to get where I am now.

-I have set the Fully qualified Internet host name to "preview.notes".

-Smtp Listener task changed to Enabled to turn on the Listener so that the server can receive messages routed via SMTP routing

-Setting up SMTP routing within the local Internet domain  (http://www.h2l.com/help/help85_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/7f9738a49efc4f58852574d500097b01?OpenDocument)

-I modified the person to use the preview@preview.notes address.

-I'm using the hMailServer (which have the local "preview.local" domain name) to send mail to preview@preview.notes.

When sending mail I got an error telling that the DNS is not set up correctly.

Is using the Domino Smtp server instead of hMailServer will solve the problem? I can Telnet the Domino Smtp Server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough points to post a comment, but when you telnet to the Domino server on port 26 can you send a message? Does the message deliver to a Domino mailbox?

How are you trying to get hMailServer how to interact with Domino SMTP? Is hMailServer forwarding emails to Domino SMTP or vica versa?

Is there any need for hMailServer? Other than port conflict is there any reason why you moved Domino SMTP to port 26? You'd be better off using IP aliases and give Domino and hMailServers different IP addresses.

Comment: There is no interaction between hMailServer and Domino, but I use the smtp of hMailServer to send an email to the Domino Server (maybe it's the problem?). Domino will never send an email, only receiving.

I am able to telnet it, but I got a strange policy restrictions. I think it's because I used a "FROM" address that was unknown by Domino.